# When returning an XElement object, how to expose the schema in the WSDL?

Tags: asp.net, linq, wcf, soap, linq-to-xml

I'm creating a SOAP WCF web service, and one of the methods returns XML data. I build the XML using LINQ to XML so the service returns an XElement type. The contract is as follows:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [XmlSerializerFormat]
 XElement AccountsGet(string integrationService, string billerID);
```

The person who is consuming the service is using Oracle SOA, and has stated that there is nowhere in the WSDL that tells him the schema of the XML returned.

Is there any way that I can expose this information in the WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to do that.

Consider that, although you may happen to be returning XML with the same schema every time, there is nothing in the method signature that would tell WCF the schema that you will always be adhering to.

You should try returning an object instead of XML.

Comment: As in an object that is serializable to XML?

Comment: You are using WCF. Most objects are serializable to XML.